# Python: using comprehensions in for loops

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7.  I have a list, and I want to use a for loop to iterate over a subset of that list subject to some condition.  Here's an illustration of what I'd like to do:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for e in l if e % 2 == 0:
    print e
```

which seems to me very neat and Pythonic, and is lovely in every way except for the small matter of a syntax error.  This alternative works:

```
for e in (e for e in l if e % 2 == 0):
    print e
```

but is ugly as sin.  Is there a way to add the conditional directly to the for loop construction, without building the generator?

Edit: you can assume that the processing and filtering that I actually want to perform on `e` are more complex than in the example above.  The processing especially doesn't belong one line.

Comment: You could `filter` (or `itertools.ifilter`) it

Comment: Nope. There isn't. The comprehension produces a filtered list and you'll have to iterate over that. Also, it's not Pythonic if it throws a SyntaxError. :)

Comment: Good point @Noufal!  Edited accordingly.  Thanks @jonrsharpe, that might be neater

Comment: `from __future__ import print [print(e) for e in l if e % 2 == 0]` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's wrong with a simple, readable solution:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for e in l:
    if e % 2 == 0:
        print e
```

You can have any amount of statements instead of just a simple `print e` and nobody has to scratch their head trying to figure out what it does.

If you need to use the sub list for something else too (not just iterate over it once), why not construct a new list instead:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
even_nums = [num for num in l if num % 2 == 0]
```

And now iterate over `even_nums`. One more line, much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `filter`

```
for i in filter(lambda x: not x%2, l):
    print i
```

or simply `list comprehension`

```
>>>[i for i in l if not i%2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't make it work that way. However here are other pythonic styles:

```
print [ e for e in l if e%2==0 ]
```

If you want to stick to your style, use this list comprehension:

```
for e in [x for x in l if x%2==0]:
    print e
```

So here e is iterating over a list defined by `[x for x in l if x%2==0]`

Well, you could always use the vanilla approach:

```
for e in l:
    if e % 2 == 0:
        print e
```

Comment: In reality, the processing I want to do with e is more complicated than printing so it has to be a multi-liner.  You're right that using a different variable name for the comprehension improves readability.  I think in this case the vanilla approach, although a little verbose, is best!

Comment: don't use list comprehensions in such cases, use generators (`for e in (x for x in l if x%2==0):`)

Answer (score 1):

No. The `for` statement requires that what comes after `in` is an expression list that evaluates to an iterable object (one that has an `__iter__`) method.

The compact alternatives are to use either a generator or a list comprehension (list having the downside that the list has to be built before the for loop starts - giving in effect two loops). You have to select one of the alternatives the language provides.

Comment: So is the for keyword in a comprehension an entirely different construct in the background?

Comment: Yes, that's a list comprehension. Although both use the same keyword, may look similar and result in a loop they are different constructs.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, l)
```